# Facebook ios sdk login error

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm currently developing an iOS app that uses the Facebook sdk for login (through FBLoginView).

Everything works well except for those who have an older version of facebook.

When they press the "login with facebook" button they reach facebook's login page as intended, but once they log in they get an error message stating that the app is not well configured, here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Facebook login error]
subtitle: "Application not configured: the developers of this app haven't properly configured it to connect to Facebook"

As I said things fail for those who have an older version of facebook only, I can currently see 3 versions around me, the one with the dark sidebar on the left, one with 2 sidebars on both sides, and the old one with a light sidebar on the left.

Is there something special to do to have it working on all version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether your app is not in Sandbox mode and if it is then set testers through the developers' settings, also check and try to create a new hashkey and to input it in the developers' settings.

Answer (score 3):

In case it happens to somebody else : I had the same error and it came from the fact that I tried to login with another login that the one I used to create the app on the facebook dashboard.
Because when your app on the facebook dashboard is in development mode, it is only visible to the account who created it...